# Regression with addtional analyis for +1 and -1 SD of X in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

This might be a beginner's question, which I haven't managed to answer despite spending hours.

I want to calculate and then plot a regression. The simple linear regression is not the problem.

```
summary(m1)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

As soon as I would add regression lines for x(hp) +1 and -1 SD I get stuck, especially because I try to avoid to "factor" x.

Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by hp+1 and -1 SD ? does SD means standard deviation ? Do you want to plot the standard deviation of the regression linear ?

Comment: Yes, I meant means standard deviations. I want to plot additional lines for the mean + 1 SD and - 1 SD

Comment: Why +1 and -1 ? Are you looking for mean+SD and mean-SD ?

Comment: Yes, Mean +SD and - SD. 1 was just to make sure that I mean one SD. Sorry for the confusion.